# Getting Variable Error - Mytable and tableName can be undefined in this Python Code. How can this be corrected?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting `Variable Error - Mytable and tableName can be undefined in this Python Code`. How can this be corrected?

```
import pyodbc

# we may be interested in finding all the drivers we have access to
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():

# print the driver name
# print(driver)

# if the driver name has '.xlsx' in it we found it!
if '.xlsx' in driver:
    myDriver = driver

# define our connection string
conn_str = (r'DRIVER={' + myDriver + '};'
                                 r'DBQ="C:\Python_Project\Tap Report for 26-Aug-2022.xlsx;'
                                 r'ReadOnly=1')  # ReadOnly set to 0 means we can edit the data.

# define our connection, autocommit MUST BE SET TO TRUE, also we can edit data.
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# loop through all the tables
for worksheet in crsr.tables():
     # display the worksheet
     print(worksheet)

     # grab the table name.
     tableName = worksheet[2]

# define our query to grab the data.
# we want this "SELECT Topic FROM [Sheet1$]"
crsr.execute("SELECT Topic FROM [{}]".format(tableName))

# print each row of data.
for row in crsr:
     print(row.Topic)
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: I have updated the indentation. Does it seems okay this time.? Apologies for any errors.

Comment: There is no `Mytable` in this code, and as for `tableName`, if the loop doesn't run at all (`crsr.tables()` is empty), then `tableName` will not get defined. You might want to initialize it with a default value for that case, or put the `crsr.execute()` line as part of the loop

Comment: Yes. Sorry variable name is myDriver

Comment: You have the same problem with both myDriver and tableName. You did not fix your indentation. It would have been easier to see if you had.